# how to add class to element if any of children have specific class in jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

how to add class to element if any of children have specific class in jquery?I have a `markup`

```
<section class="cc01 cc01v0 cpad" >
   <div class="cc01w1 cwidth">
      <div class="ocode ocode-initialized">
         <div class="ocode-bttn" data-success="Copied to Clipboard" data-error="Error: Could not Copy">
            <div><a href="#copy">Copy</a></div>
            <div class="ocode-success">Copied to Clipboard</div>
            <div class="ocode-error">Error: Could not Copy</div>
         </div>
         <textarea readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1"></textarea>
      </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

.I want to `addClass`('test') to `section element` if any of children have `ocode` class .If any of children have class `ocode` i want to add class `test` in the section.

https://jsbin.com/cajavivuru/edit?html,js,output

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    'use strict';
    console.log('cgggggggg11111');
        console.log('cgggggggg');
        $('.cc01.cc01v0.cpad').each(function () {
           console.log('===========');
          
          if($(this).children('ocode').hasClass('ocode')){
            $(this).addClass('test')
          }
           //console.log($(this).css({'background':'red'}))
        });

        
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reverse, you can get all elements with `.ocode` class and
using `$().parents()` function, you can get all parent elements of that `.ocode` selector.

And among those parent elements, you can check the tagName of them and for the matched `SECTION` tagName, add `.test` class.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".ocode").each(function () {
    $(this).parents().each(function () {
      if($(this).prop("tagName") === "SECTION") {
        $(this).addClass("test");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<section class="cc01 cc01v0 cpad">
  <div class="cc01w1 cwidth">
    <div class="ocode ocode-initialized">
      <div class="ocode-bttn" data-success="Copied to Clipboard" data-error="Error: Could not Copy">
        <div><a href="#copy">Copy</a></div>
        <div class="ocode-success">Copied to Clipboard</div>
        <div class="ocode-error">Error: Could not Copy</div>
      </div>
      <textarea readonly="readonly" tabindex="-1"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```